# How to define a GitLab CI job to depend on either one or one another previous job?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I want to define a pipeline to compile, deploy to target and test my project.

This should happen in two distinct ways: an incremental (hopefully fast) build at each commit and a full build scheduled at night.

The following `.gitlab-ci.yml` has all jobs marked "manual" for testing purposes.

```
stages:
    - build
    - deploy
    - test

variables:
    BUILD_ARTIFACTS_DIR: "artifacts"

build-incremental:
    timeout: 5h 
    stage: build
    script:
        - echo "Building"
        - ./ci/do-prep
        - echo "done."
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - $BUILD_ARTIFACTS_DIR/
    variables:
        BUILD_TOP_DIR: "/workspace/builds"
    tags:
        - yocto
    when: manual

build-nightly:
    timeout: 5h
    stage: build
    script:
        - echo "Building"
        - ./ci/do-prep
        - echo "done."
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - $BUILD_ARTIFACTS_DIR/
    tags:
        - yocto
    when: manual

deploy:
    stage: deploy
    script:
        - echo "Deploying..."
        - ./ci/do-deploy
        - echo "done."
    tags:
        - yocto
    dependencies:
        - build
    when: manual

test:
    stage: test
    script:
        - echo "Testing..."
        - ./ci/do-test
        - echo "done."
    tags:
        - yocto
    dependencies:
        - deploy
    when: manual
```

This fails with message: `deploy job: undefined dependency: build`.

Cow do I explain to GitLab `deploy` stage needs either `build-incremental` or `build-nightly` artifacts?

Later I will have to understand how to trigger `build-incremental` at commit and `build-nightly` using a schedule, but that seems to be a different problem.

Answer (score 5):

For your scenario, there are two separate paths through your pipeline depending on the "source": a 'push' or a 'schedule'. You can get the source of the pipeline with the `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` variable. I build these paths separately at first, then combine them:

```yaml
# First source: push events
stages:
  build
  deploy
  test

variables:
    BUILD_ARTIFACTS_DIR: "artifacts"

build-incremental:
    timeout: 5h 
    stage: build
    script:
        - echo "Building"
        - ./ci/do-prep
        - echo "done."
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - $BUILD_ARTIFACTS_DIR/
    variables:
        BUILD_TOP_DIR: "/workspace/builds"
    tags:
        - yocto
    rules:
      - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'push'
        when: manual
      - when: never

deploy-incremental:
    stage: deploy
    script:
        - echo "Deploying..."
        - ./ci/do-deploy
        - echo "done."
    tags:
        - yocto
    needs: ['build-incremental']
    rules:
      - if $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'push'
        when: always
      - when: never

test-incremental:
    stage: test
    script:
        - echo "Testing..."
        - ./ci/do-test
        - echo "done."
    tags:
        - yocto
    needs: ['deploy-incremental']
    rules:
      - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'push'
        when: always
      - when: never
```

In this path, if the source is a push, the build step will run upon manual input, otherwise it will never run. Then, the deploy-incremental step will run automatically (without waiting for other jobs or stages) as long as the source is a push, otherwise it will never run. Finally the `test-incremental` job will run automatically without waiting for other jobs or stages if it's a `push` like above.

Now we can build the `schedule` path:

```yaml
# Scheduled path:

stages:
  build
  deploy
  test

variables:
    BUILD_ARTIFACTS_DIR: "artifacts"

build-schedule:
    timeout: 5h 
    stage: build
    script:
        - echo "Building"
        - ./ci/do-prep
        - echo "done."
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - $BUILD_ARTIFACTS_DIR/
    variables:
        BUILD_TOP_DIR: "/workspace/builds"
    tags:
        - yocto
    rules:
      - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE === 'schedule'
        when: manual
      - when: never

deploy-schedule:
    stage: deploy
    script:
        - echo "Deploying..."
        - ./ci/do-deploy
        - echo "done."
    tags:
        - yocto
    needs: ['build-schedule']
    rules:
      - if $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'schedule'
        when: always
      - when: never

test-schedule:
    stage: test
    script:
        - echo "Testing..."
        - ./ci/do-test
        - echo "done."
    tags:
        - yocto
    needs: ['deploy-schedule']
    rules:
      - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'schedule'
        when: always
      - when: never
```

This works the same way as the `push` path, but we check to see if the source is `schedule`.

Now we can combine the two paths:

```yaml
Combined result:
stages:
  build
  deploy
  test

variables:
    BUILD_ARTIFACTS_DIR: "artifacts"

build-incremental:
    timeout: 5h 
    stage: build
    script:
        - echo "Building"
        - ./ci/do-prep
        - echo "done."
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - $BUILD_ARTIFACTS_DIR/
    variables:
        BUILD_TOP_DIR: "/workspace/builds"
    tags:
        - yocto
    rules:
      - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'push'
        when: manual
      - when: never

build-schedule:
    timeout: 5h 
    stage: build
    script:
        - echo "Building"
        - ./ci/do-prep
        - echo "done."
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - $BUILD_ARTIFACTS_DIR/
    variables:
        BUILD_TOP_DIR: "/workspace/builds"
    tags:
        - yocto
    rules:
      - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'schedule'
        when: manual
      - when: never

deploy-incremental:
    stage: deploy
    script:
        - echo "Deploying..."
        - ./ci/do-deploy
        - echo "done."
    tags:
        - yocto
    needs: ['build-incremental']
    rules:
      - if $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'push'
        when: always
      - when: never

deploy-schedule:
    stage: deploy
    script:
        - echo "Deploying..."
        - ./ci/do-deploy
        - echo "done."
    tags:
        - yocto
    needs: ['build-schedule']
    rules:
      - if $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'schedule'
        when: always
      - when: never

test-incremental:
    stage: test
    script:
        - echo "Testing..."
        - ./ci/do-test
        - echo "done."
    tags:
        - yocto
    needs: ['deploy-incremental']
    rules:
      - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'push'
        when: always
      - when: never

test-schedule:
    stage: test
    script:
        - echo "Testing..."
        - ./ci/do-test
        - echo "done."
    tags:
        - yocto
    needs: ['deploy-schedule']
    rules:
      - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'schedule'
        when: always
      - when: never
```

A pipeline like this is tedious and takes a bit to build, but works great when you have multiple paths/ways to build the project.

Answer (score 5):

To tell Gitlab that your `deploy` stage needs certain artifacts from a specific job: Try naming `dependencies` by job name. In `deploy` you are defining a  dependency with  `build` which is a `stage` name  not the one of the job you want to pick the artifact.
Example:

```
deploy:
stage: deploy
script:
    - echo "Deploying..."
    - ./ci/do-deploy
    - echo "done."
tags:
    - yocto
dependencies:
    - build-incremental
when: manual
```

more info and examples here [dependencies](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#dependencies)

Comment: This does not answer the main question on how to run a job that depends on either of previous jobs. It just recomends to depend on only one of them.